# Is the squared norm of the four-momentum of a system of N-particles equal to the total mass of the N particles?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, mass-energy

I know that for a particle, $p \cdot p=\eta_{\mu\nu } p^{\mu }p^{\nu }=p_{\nu }p^{\nu }=-{E^{2} \ c^{2}+| \mathbf {p} |^{2}=-m^{2}c^{2}}$ is obviously invariant, where $m$ is the rest/proper mass of the particle, $p$ the four-vector momentum and $\eta_{\mu\nu }$ the (Minkowski) metric tensor of special relativity.

What I want to know is, for a system of N particles, each with different momenta, is the sum $(p_1^\mu + p_2^\mu + \dots + p_N^\mu)^2$ equal to the rest mass of the system? It seems to not make sense, since there would be extra cross terms and surely $((p_1^\mu)^2 + (p_2^\mu)^2 + \dots + (p_N^\mu)^2)$ should be the total rest mass? Is $(p_1^\mu + p_2^\mu + \dots + p_N^\mu)^2$ instead equal to just the TOTAL mass of that system? My thinking is that $(p_1^\mu + p_2^\mu + \dots + p_N^\mu)^2 = -{E_{tot}^{2} / c^{2}+| \mathbf {p_{tot}} |^{2}=-M_{tot}^{2}c^{2}}$ where $M_{tot}$ is (maybe) the relativistic mass. If this is true, what does $M_{tot}$ even mean? I thought the total mass of a system would be the sum of the rest masses, unless of course it's talking about relativistic mass which is dependent on the motion.

Could someone please shed light as to why it does kind of make sense, but I would like a more rigorous explanation? Thanks.

Comment: Short answer: yes, and therefore the total mass is not equal to the sum of the masses. A full answer would include an explanation for why this makes sense.

Comment: The guiding principle is the following: in order for some expression to make sense, this expression must arise naturally in course of practical calculations, not as idle speculations.

Comment: Idle speculations are what make physics, physics though.

Comment: @jambajuice: For example, the sum of particle masses $m_1+m_2+...+m_N$ is constant by definition of each mass as a coefficient in the corresponding equation, but never arises in practical calculations.

Answer (score 2):

In special relativity, rest mass of a system is proportional to net rest energy of that system:

$$
m = \frac{E}{c^2}.
$$

If in systems' rest frame system components move faster they have more energy, hence the system has higher rest energy and corresponding rest mass.

One cannot just add rest masses of the components, that would ignore their kinetic energy. And in more complicated situations where the components interact, it would ignore the potential energy of interaction.

Comment: Is this really "rest energy" though, if the particles are moving? Or do you just mean the total energy?

Comment: It is rest energy of the system in the sense "energy in the frame where the system as a whole does not move".

Comment: And just to make sure I'm getting this from the comment down below correct. Is this invariant even in a frame where the system does move?

Comment: What do you mean by "invariant even in a frame"? Rest energy is value of total energy in single, very particular frame.

Comment: You can prove for yourself if something is invariant or not, if it is conceptually unclear.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia: invariant mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_mass#:%7E:text=The%20invariant%20mass%2C%20rest%20mass,overall%20motion%20of%20the%20system.)

The quantity you are asking about is known as invariant mass. You correctly point out that it only makes sense as the sum of rest masses (up to factors of $c^2$) in non-relativistic limit. If particles are moving relativistically it loses a simple interpretation as the sum of rest masses but it is still a useful Lorentz-invariant quantity. As pointed out in the other answer, it is equal to rest energy, i.e. energy in the frame where system as a whole does not move (which means its' spatial momentum is zero):

$$p_1^\mu + p_2^\mu + ... + p_N^\mu = P^\mu = (E/c,0,0,0)\Longrightarrow (p_1^\mu + p_2^\mu + ... + p_N^\mu)^2 = M_{inv}^2c^2 = \dfrac{E^2}{c^2}$$

If net spatial momentum is non-zero, then from this definition the net energy and net momentum are connected to each other by exactly the same formula as for one particle:

$$p_1^\mu + p_2^\mu + ... + p_N^\mu = P^\mu = (E'/c,\mathbf{P'})\Longrightarrow (p_1^\mu + p_2^\mu + ... + p_N^\mu)^2 = M_{inv}^2c^2 = \dfrac{E'^2}{c^2} - \mathbf{P'}^2$$

Comment: And in the case where the net momentum isn't 0?

Comment: I've added this case to the answer.

Comment: Right ok. So it is essentially just the net relativistic mass? I sort of see why this is invariant, but what does $M_{inv}$ then actually represent? Is this just saying that the relative masses in that frame must obey this quantity, but for all we care, one mass could be a tenth of the other - it doesn't matter so long as it obeys this?

Comment: A square (in the sense of contraction with Minkowski metric) of any vector is always Lorentz-invariant - so the invariant mass is truly Lorentz invariant. The concept of relativistic mass is not widely used these days - it is preferred that the word mass is reserved to something Lorentz-invariant. What was called relativistic mass today is just considered as relativistic energy (up to $c^2$).

Comment: Right, since energy and mass are equivalent...